# How to export data as csv from snowsight?

Tags: csv, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using [snowsight](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-snowsight.html) to access my snowflake database. I searched the snowsight docs on how to export table as csv but unable to find that option. Does anyone know if we can export table as csv from snowsight?

Answer (score 0):

You can run

```
select * from <table-name>;
```

and export the output in CSV, as shown below:

[image]